# Using reference causes no warning about undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior

I've been studying undefined behavior examples for C++, and I've found following one:

```
int a = 0;
a = a++;
```

Tried it with `g++ -Wall -Wextra` and it got me warning about sequence point.

But then I thought about another situation using reference:

```
int a = 0;
int &b = a;
b = a++;
```

This one didn't shout on me about sequence point. It seems almost obvious that it should.
Is there any good explanation why those two examples are treated differently by compiler?

Comment: Probably GCC is just not smart enough.

Comment: C++ is a complex language, and a compiler like GCC is an *extremely* complex program. It simply can't handle every corner case that might arise, and even if it could handle this specific case it could have unexpected consequences somewhere else. Also, unless one of the people working on GCC sees this question, it's really unanswerable.

Comment: Visual C++ with the default warning levels is quite happy with the above code.

Comment: For the most part, diagnosing undefined behavior is a courtesy. In this case, it's simply not extended.

Comment: But - there are lots of examples of undefined behavior which the compiler won't issue warnings for.  Take threading for example; it won't warn you if 2 threads decide to play with the same memory without a mutex.  C++ gives so much rope to people that the compiler tries to limit how much people wrap it around their neck; but a concerted effort will always find a way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That might seem obvious UB, but you have to understand that there are uncountably many different ways to violate the sequencing rules. And proving whether any particular expression is in violation is a slow and complex process, and sometimes turns out to be impossible. This is why the violation of these rules has been specified undefined behaviour in the standard, instead of ill-formed which would have required a diagnostic in every possible violation.

So, the compiler has to draw a line somewhere, and not spend resources to validate all expressions. Your test shows two expressions that are on opposite sides of that "line".

Comment: I beg to defer. There is a **countable** infinity of UB possible. And only a finite number if we consider physical restrictions like finite memory or finite time ;) (just nitpicking for the fun of it)

Comment: @YSC yeah, I may be exaggerating a bit :) For dramatic effect.